# Do we know how far Caesar traveled with the main group?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, planet-of-the-apes-2011, war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes

In *War For the Planet of the Apes*, When the main group of apes and Caesar all travel together,

> to the new home at the end of the movie,

do we know how far they actually traveled?

Early in the movie, Caesar's son and Rocket indicated that their destination was far away, over mountains and through a desert. Yet,

> since they had no supplies and Caesar survived the whole trip,

it seems unlikely that they ended up going to the same place the scouts spoke of.

I'm not familiar enough with the geography of Western USA to make a good guess here. I'm just trying to reconcile their earlier plans to go far, with the low chance they actually went that far, but that they still apparently went from a snowy, wintry area to a lush, green area.

So, where did they go and/or how far did they travel?

Answer (score 2):

We can infer it was likely from Sierra County in California to likely another place in California over a mountain range.

Since Bad Ape was from Sierra Zoo, most probably in Sierra County, California, it is likely that they crossed over a mountain range in Sierra county.

Here is a link to a Wikipedia article with a list of Californian mountain ranges: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountain_ranges_of_California